# Internal compiler error - Templated conversion operator in switch expression

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement, implicit-conversion

The following code crashes the Microsoft compiler:

```
class Var
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    operator T () const
    { }
};

int main()
{
    Var v;
    switch (v)
    { }
}
```

My question: Is the code correct or should the compiler give an appropriate error? Is an unambiguous conversion to an integral type possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "crashes the compiler?"  What do you mean by "is the code correct?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey `fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.` ... blahblah ... please report to microsoft (I did report the bug). On the line of the conversion operator.

Comment: Even if the code is incorrect, it shouldn't crash the compiler...Your `operator T` doesn't actually return anything, though, so that's UB right there even if it compiled.

Comment: First of `operator T()` must return something. Second, `switch` waits for an `int`.

Comment: You can only use `class Var` in `switch` statement if it can be converted into an integral value.

Comment: @40two why switch expects int?

Comment: @40two: worse - `switch` wants "integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists" (**6.4.2/2**). If it wanted `int` specifically, it could have gotten one with `v.operator int()`. But `v` is convertible to anything, so the statement is ambiguous.

Comment: @40two It does not matter what is inside the function body of the operator, the compiler crashes regardless. I just stripped it to keep the code minimal.

Comment: @typ1232 you made it too minimal, it should be correct.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your comment has answer quality! Thank you for looking up the quote.

Comment: Compiler crashing (ICE) is, of course, **always a bug**. If the code is incorrect (as here), then this is merely a minor nuisance. But if the code is correct, an ICE is really annoying and requires an (often tedious) work around.

Comment: @Slava I meant requires expression of integer type but felt `int` was shorter :). Sorry for unintended misleading.

Comment: I tried it in Studio 2013 and also got the crash. The interesting thing is that the editor flags the `switch(v)` with a red squiggle and the pop-up "Error: expression must have integral or enum type".

Comment: @RobK Curiously, IntelliSense in VS is backed by a [compiler other than MSVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx). It's common for the two to flag different sets of errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler crashing is always a bug, this code does not compile on either `gcc` or `clang` but both provide an error without crashing. For `clang` the error is:

```
error: statement requires expression of integer type ('Var' invalid)
switch (v)
^       ~
```

`gcc` provides the following error:

```
error: ambiguous default type conversion from 'Var'
 switch (v)
          ^
```

Also, note that flowing off the end of a value returning function is undefined behavior in C++.

**Update**

Adding:

```
operator int () const
{ return 0; }
```

to the class brings about different results from `clang` and `gcc`.

See [Classes with both template and non-template conversion operators in the condition of switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25047109/1708801) for a discussion on whether `gcc` or `clang` is correct. My interpretation of `N3323` implies [clang is correct on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25048219/1708801).

**Filed bug report**

I [filed a bug report for this ICE](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/934051/class-instance-with-only-a-templated-conversion-function-used-in-a-switch-statement-causes-ice), so far no response. Even though this seems like an odd corner case it does cause an internal compiler error which should be fixed.